# error: legacy-install-failure - unable to install mysqlclient on Windows

Tags: python, pip, mysql-connector

I am unable to install mysqlclient via pip. I am working on Windows 11 and using python-3.9.13 and pip 22.1.2 and installed MySQL 8.0.29

Below is the installation output and error snip. Could you please look into this?

Thank you in advance

```
(myenv) D:\New_Folder\github\project\projectName>pip install mysqlclient==1.3.14
Collecting mysqlclient==1.3.14
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.14.tar.gz (91 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for mysqlclient, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for mysqlclient did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [34 lines of output]
      D:\New_Folder\github\myenv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:717: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'distribution-name' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'distribution_name' instead
        warnings.warn(
      D:\New_Folder\github\myenv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:717: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'build-requires' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'build_requires' instead
        warnings.warn(
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
      copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\MySQLdb
X86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> mysqlclient

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```